# **Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException**

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

**I am trying to fetch some records from a txt file and put those in Database in the following  Java Program**

```
package Java_Demo;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Jdbc_Demo {


    public static void main(String ...args)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException,FileNotFoundException {

        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("C:/Users/steve-pc/Desktop/Employees.txt");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(fin);
        s.useDelimiter(",|\\n");

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.22.22.131:1521:orcl","Demo","demo");
        while(s.hasNext())
        {

        PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("Insert into Employee values(?,?,?)");

        String name=s.next();
        int  id=s.nextInt();
        int sal=s.nextInt();

        st.setString(1,name);
        st.setInt(2,id);
        st.setInt(3,sal);

        int result=st.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Records Changed: "+ result);

        }
        con.close();

    }

 }
```

**The txt file from which I am fetching the data has following format**

Steve,12349,550000

Mark,54321,250000

Bill,65478,350000

**Additionally the EMPLOYEE table has following format**

Name         Id          Salary

Varachar2  Number  Number

**But the code is generating following ERROR**

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Java_Demo.Jdbc_Demo.main(Jdbc_Demo.java:24)
```

Comment: int  id=s.nextInt(); & int sal=s.nextInt(); is taking in integer while your scanner will read your file as String instead. Convert it into integer.

Comment: @Sky I don't think so.. if I am keeping only single row in my txt file, then it is workin perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the change as below:

```
public class ScannerTest {


    public static void main(String ...args)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException,FileNotFoundException {

        File f =new File("/home/rahul/Desktop/emp.txt");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(f);
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.22.22.131:1521:orcl","Demo","demo");
        while(s.hasNext())
        {

        PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("Insert into Employee values(?,?,?)");

        String rcd = s.next();
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(rcd);
        s1.useDelimiter(",|\\n");

        String name=s1.next();
        int  id=s1.nextInt();
        int sal=s1.nextInt();

        st.setString(1,name);
        st.setInt(2,id);
        st.setInt(3,sal);

        int result=st.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Records Changed: "+ result);

        }
        con.close();

    }

 }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the logic of using "rcd" variable

Comment: IN above logic, by using first scanner you are reading a line as a string and this string is being passed to another scanner which is splitting the string on the given pattern and you are calling nextInt().

Answer (score 2):

s.nextInt(); is giving error for you. Because the scanner next cannot be converted into integer. I would suggest, you use s.next for all three and then Integer.parseInt(String) method to convert them into int

Comment: I don't think so.. if I am keeping only single row in my txt file, then it is workin perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you have whitespace in your file?

If so, you can use something like this to ignore it

```
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*|\\n");
```

Or read each token as a string and then tidy and convert to int.